# How get user input integer in golang into function

Tags: go

I recently started learning golang, i will get user input within **myInput** function with `fmt.Scan()` but when I put it inside the function `fmt.Scan()`, does not get user input;

`fmt.Scan()` not working below exmaple:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func myInput(p1 *int, p2 *int) {
    fmt.Println("Enter text : ")
    fmt.Scan(*p1)
    fmt.Println("Enter text : ")
    fmt.Scan(*p2)
}

func rect(x int, y int, a *int, p *int) {
    *a = x * y
    *p = 2 *(x + y)
}

func main() {

    var length, width, area, perimeter int
    myInput(&length, &width)
    rect(length, width, &area, &perimeter)
    fmt.Println(length, width, area, perimeter)

}
```

How solve this problem, thanks,
and Why not working Scan() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete `&` in scan method

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func myInput(p1 *int, p2 *int) {
    fmt.Println("Enter text : ")
    fmt.Scan(p1)
    fmt.Println("Enter text : ")
    fmt.Scan(p2)
}

func rect(x int, y int, a *int, p *int) {
    *a = x * y
    *p = 2 *(x + y)
}

func main() {

    var length, width, area, perimeter int
    myInput(&length, &width)
    rect(length, width, &area, &perimeter)
    fmt.Println(length, width, area, perimeter)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for answer it should be like this

As you are assigning the value to the pointer variable you must specify it with pointer to that variable *var_name

It should be like,
//with scanf

```
fmt.Scanf("%v",&*var_name)
```

//with scan

```
fmt.Scan(&*var_name)
```

Here is how above code should be like

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

func myInput(p1 *int, p2 *int) {
        fmt.Println("Enter length : ")
        fmt.Scan(&*p1)
        fmt.Println("Enter width : ")
        fmt.Scan(&*p2)
}

func rect(x int, y int, a *int, p *int) {
        *a = x * y
        *p = 2 * (x + y)
}

func main() {

        var length, width, area, perimeter int
        myInput(&length, &width)
        rect(length, width, &area, &perimeter)
        fmt.Println(length, width, area, perimeter)

}
```

Comment: You don't need to dereference, then take a reference again in 
```
fmt.Scan(&*p1)
```
`p1` is already a pointer, so you can just pass it to `Scan`:
```
fmt.Scan(p1)
```